# How do i display each word of string with different color in YUI DataTable?

Tags: yui

How do i display each word of string with different color in YUI DataTable?

I need "Mark" color is blue and "good" is red.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSlvc.png

```
<script>
    YUI().use("datatable", function(Y) {

    var records = [
    { item: "widget", cost: 23.57, price: 47.5 },
    { item: "gadget", cost: 0.11, price: "Mark is good " },
    { item: "sprocket", cost: 4.08, price: 3.75 }
    ];

    var table = new Y.DataTable({
    columns: ["item","cost", "price"],
        data: records
    });
    table.render("#example");
    }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a column formatter.  Split the value string by whitespace `o.value.split(/\s/)` and inspect each word.  If it's one of your target words, wrap it with an element.  Assign that element a css class appropriate to add the color.

E.g. https://gist.github.com/2872732